# Will Visual Studio 2008 work on Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit)?

Tags: windows-7, installation, visual-studio

I would like to know whether Visual Studio 2008 works on Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit).
I am specific about the 64 bit Home Premium version of Windows 7.
Regards,
Naveen Jose

Comment: Posted as a comment as I can't answer specifically for the Home editions, but it certainly works on 64 bit professional. I can't imagine why it wouldn't work for you though.

Comment: Same. Definitely works on 64-bit professional and enterprise. Can't imagine why it wouldn't work on home.

Comment: Fairly sure this is a duplicate, but (as usual) I can't find it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It works. I run VS 2008 in my Home Premium 64bit right now :)

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth if you are doing ASP.NET development Home Premium lacks certain IIS features that you get in the business and above versions - check [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753473.aspx) to see if there is anything you might need.

Answer (score 2):

[In](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxsetup/thread/3e793860-13ce-4cdc-939b-bb70194efdb5) [these](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/c64c97a9-2c66-4884-b641-fdb31ac680ef) [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/vssetup/thread/5c574714-ea4f-43a3-8331-c77a42671ffe) posts, Microsoft don't specifically state an answer to your exact set up, however they do state the express editions are supported on Home Premium x64 and that the non express editions are supported on Windows 7.

I realise they don't specifically include your scenario, but I think it is safe to assume that it is implied.